# chrome extensions building (HTML text to clipboard saver)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very far for Web development. I need a Chrome extension which will copy page root directory html text to clipboard.

There is single file which is doing this job, but it working very slowly.
I make extension which downloads the page html with text file. But I want just copy . And in exe application paste.

```js
    function copyTextToClipboard()
{
    var copyFrom=document.documentElement.innerHTML;

    var file = new Blob([copyFrom], {type: 'text/plain'});

    var atag = document.createElement("a");
    
    var today = new Date();

    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+' '+today.getHours()+today.getMinutes()+today.getSeconds();

    atag.href=URL.createObjectURL(file);
    atag.download=date+".txt";
    atag.click();
    atag.remove();
    //console.log(date);
    var t =setTimeout(function(){ copyTextToClipboard() },10000);
    
}

copyTextToClipboard();
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found solutation. This code copying html file, in txt format every 5 second.

function copyTextToClipboard()
{

```
var copyFrom=document.documentElement.innerText;

if(copyFrom!=null)
{
    
    var area = document.createElement("textarea");
    area.value=copyFrom;
    document.body.appendChild(area);
    area.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(area);

}

var t =setTimeout(function(){ copyTextToClipboard() },5000);
```

}
copyTextToClipboard();